# Android HttpClient cookies

Tags: java, android, cookies, httpclient, cookiestore

I am trying to make an app for a website. The Login works fine but when I try to send GET requests now the session id cookie isn't send. The HttpContext with a CookieStorage is set up like this:

```
public static final HttpContext LOCALCONTEXT = new BasicHttpContext();
LOCALCONTEXT.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);
```

than that's the login:

```
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost, LOCALCONTEXT);
```

and that's the GET request:

```
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpGet, LoginActivity.LOCALCONTEXT);.
```

With

```
Log.d(LoginActivity.NAME, "Cookie1:= " + LoginActivity.LOCALCONTEXT.getAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE).toString());
```

i logged the saved cookies before and after the GET request. They are the right ones. But than i sniffed the traffic of the emulator and the cookie isn't sent.
Why?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
Problem was that I logged in to the page "http://WWW.arenakampf.de" and sent the GET to "http://arenakampf.de" :/